# STCS05DR LED driver

Tags: power-supply, buck, driver, led-driver, constant-current

I am trying to use the STCS05DR constant current LED driver IC by STMicro in my buck converter design to indicate input power with a 1206 red LED.

The input power is a variable DC battery source (Milwaukee M18 battery) up to 20V. The reason I went this route is obviously to keep the brightness of the LED relatively unchanged with the gradually falling input voltage over time.

I have had no success using this IC and am wondering what am I missing to utilize this correctly.

The first time I plugged the circuit in I ended up releasing the magic smoke from the IC, the LED lit up very briefly beforehand.

Upon troubleshooting, I noticed that pin 6 which is GND was disconnected, which is strange because I imported the KiCad symbol and footprint directly from SnapEDA, therefore I was surprised to find GND unconnected by default. I scraped away some of the solder mask on the ground plane in front of the pin and solder jumped the pin the plane to connect it.

After replacing the burnt up chip with a new one and also populating a new LED, the second time I plugged the circuit in the LED fried but the IC stayed working (I think).

When measuring the open circuit voltage across the LED I got 19ish volts, which seems like a lot that would make sense why it would fry the LED.  I have the current set in my use case to 20mA with a 5 ohm resistor across FB and GND, which according to the datasheet is the correct way to set the current limit.

PWM I have left floating which I wouldn't think would have an affect on anything.

[image]

[image]

Do I still need a resistor on the output to drop the voltage? Wouldn't this defeat the purpose of the IC? I also don't have a *CDRAIN* capacitor strapped across DRAIN and FB resistor such as the datasheet application suggests.

[image]

[image]

Comment: C4 on the feedback pin looks like a mistake? That's probably going to prevent the converter from adjusting the output voltage. Also, show your layout.

Comment: That circuit is the main buck conversion circuit and is irrelevant from the led driver issue, I just included that portion for reference. However you are kind of correct, I put a large value polarized capacitor there when it was supposed to be just a small 1nF unpolarized cap per datasheet recommendation for the LM2596-ADJ application.

Comment: Measuring a high open-circuit LED voltage is not unexpected. The IC is trying to push 20mA through an open circuit and raising the voltage to try to achieve that. If you replace the LED with a 100R resistor then you should expect to measure 2V for 20mA.

Comment: Your schematic is really hard to read. You should make the net labels read horizontally.

A quick scan of the datasheet doesn't seem to say that the PWM line is pulled high and/or you can leave it floating. I think this should be tied to Vcc. Maybe via a current limiting resistor. 

Are you sure you didn't connect the supply up backwards?

Comment: I am sure I don't have the supply connected backwards, I have a mosfet reverse polarity protection circuit implemented for that specific purpose. I actually did have the PWM line tied to VCC previously before I found out about the disconnected ground, though I decided to cut it to leave it floating, I suppose I could tie it back to VCC to see what happens. Also I appreciate the advice on the net labels.

Comment: From a layout point of view (and I appreciate this is not the root of your issue) you shouldn't have vias in the middle of the pads of the electrolytic and the LED.

Comment: When you say you measured the open circuit voltage across the LED do you mean after you'd removed the fried LED and before you replaced it?

Comment: @DiBosco thank you for the constructive criticism, I've laid out several pcbs over the years for both work and hobby projects and have always wondered what the preference is for via placement and if it just boils down to user preference. This is my first time ever using KiCad for schematic capture and pcb layout.

Comment: @DiBosco I measured the open circuit voltage after I fried and removed the second LED, the first one I wasn't sure if it was still good or not since I blew the IC, so I figured just to be on the safe side replace it. So currently when I apply power without an LED on the driver IC seems normal not getting warm or anything and the voltage across the open LED pad is approximately 19V. The current setting resistor also still measures 5ish Ohms.

Comment: OK, one thing I hadn't checked earlier was the pinout on the symbol. Looks completely wrong to me. Ground is pin 6, not 2. PWM is pin 2, not 3. Disc is 8, not 4. And you have two pins numbered 4. The PCB, I *think* looks about right though. What's going on there?

Could the new LED have been put in backwards?

Comment: Yes I'm aware the symbol pinout looks wrong, however the PCB footprint for the IC was almost correct, all I had to do was connect pin 6 to ground which I mentioned previously. I did also verify polarity on the LED before populating but the polarity marking even on 1206 sized LEDs is so small perhaps I missed it. I'm going to put a 100-Ohm resistor in place of the LED and see if I do indeed get 2V across.

Comment: "PWM I have left floating which I wouldn't think would have an affect on anything" and how did you come to this conclusion? PWM is on/off input, so if you want your LED to be ON you have to pull it high. Same goes for bypass capacitors, they are in the datasheet for a reason. Ignoring the datasheet and then asking why it doesn't work will not take you far.

Comment: If you're measuring 19V across an actual LED (and not just across the empty LED pads), then either the LED is backwards, or it's dead (or maybe even both - some LEDs don't like large reverse voltages).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, when I went to scrape away at the solder mask on the ground plane to connect the previously disconnected pin 6 to GND, I actually ended up connecting pin 7 to GND. This was a very stupid mistake I can't believe I hadn't noticed before hand.

After connecting pin 6 to GND and populating a new LED, the circuit works fine and the LED lights up appropriately when power is applied.

The PWM pin is not required to be tied to GND nor pulled up to VCC for this IC to work properly, nor is CDRAIN strictly required.

Comment: "The PWM pin is not required to be tied to GND nor pulled up to VCC for this IC to work properly" where in datasheet does it say this? because if not in datasheet then you just got lucky, or simply did not encounter intermittent problems yet